# THREE.JS -Stereo Effect Antialiasing

Tags: three.js, blender

Here i have done virtual reality of interior using stereo camera  three.js,In desktop browser it works fine,but in mobile browser the mesh is getting gitter, Antialiasing is not working,Please help me,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Antialiasing is **NOT** supported in all browsers.

Check **[this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17224795/1697459)** for more information.

Go **[here](http://benchung.com/antialiasing-three-js/)** to check for support in your specific browser.