# The webglrenderer antialias doesn't work on some devices?

Tags: javascript, three.js, antialiasing

On my macbook pro with Chrome, the antialias works well.

[image: pic on macbook pro with chrome]
However on my iphone6s with Chrome or Safari, it doesn't work anymore with the same code.
[image: pic on iphone with Safari]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Antialiasing not working in Three.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224795/antialiasing-not-working-in-three-js)

Comment: A tester can be found here: http://benchung.com/antialiasing-three-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the pixelratio?

```
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

**Edit:** [iOS does not support antialiasing at the moment](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7655)

Comment: That worked, I test in macbook pro window.devicePixelRatio is 2 and in iphone6s window.devicePixelRatio is 3. Thanks!